# Podcast RSS Validates But Doesn't Play

Tags: rss, podcast

I have 2 podcast RSS Feeds that almost identical. One works and one doesn't. Both validate.

https://neilrogers.org/podcast/  (works great!)

I have a 2nd feed that validates with a single show on it. It validates, but when I try to play it in OverCast nothing happens. It sees the show and the description but doesn't play.

https://neilrogers.org/podcast/discovered/  (not playing!)

I'm stumped. I use the same code to generate the 2nd feed that I used for the first. Same audio host (archive.org).

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From "[How to Fix Common Podcast RSS Feed Problems](https://theaudacitytopodcast.com/how-to-fix-common-podcast-rss-feed-problems-tap271/)", the next three causes could be of relevance in your case:

> - **Caches**: Website caching, CDN/external caching, and feed caching may need to be refreshed for your latest episode to display.
> - **Duplicated posts**: Some tools may allow you to duplicate a post, but it in rare cases, it may also duplicate the globally unique identifier (GUID), so most RSS clients won't recognize the new post as a new episode.
> - **Migration**: When moving your RSS feed from one place to another, ensure your new feed-generator will also migrate the GUIDs. Blubrry, PowerPress, and Libsyn are smart enough to do that; I can't say the same for other providers.